# Creating a Foundation-style Block Grid in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, zurb-foundation

In Zurb Foundation 3+, they have a CSS construct of a "block grid" which is an unordered list where you can specify the number of items in a row.

[Here's their docs on it.](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html)

There's no way I can see to do this in Bootstrap 3; there's only columns.  I'd like to have the ability to have a repeated element (such as a LI) display easily as a responsive grid, where I can specify how many across by breakpoint, as in Foundation.

I figure I can roll my own, but wanted to see if anyone had suggestions or had come across this before.

Comment: I've run across this exact problem several times with Bootstrap/Wordpress. Typically I'll set up a foreach loop with a counter for my li's. If it is equal to 0 I'll echo out a new row, and when the counter is equal to the number of columns I want in the layout, I'll echo out closing tag for the row and reset the counter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I too wish this was feature in BS3. You'll have to create your own solution.

My typical workaround is just as Foundation does it, by using percentages to define width, the nth-child selector, and adjusting margins.

```
[class*="block-grid-"] {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 -0.55556rem;
}

[class*="block-grid-"] > li {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0.55556rem 1.11111rem;
}

.small-block-grid-3 > li {
    width: 33.33333%;
    list-style: none;
}

.small-block-grid-3 > li:nth-of-type(1n) {
    clear: none;
}

.small-block-grid-3 > li:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: using bootstrap 2.3.x.  The third element was wrapping to the next line.  I changed the width in the small-block-grid-3 > li to 30% and problem was solved.

Comment: How are you using this? `<ul class="block-grid-3"><li class="small-block-grid-3"></li></ul>`

Comment: What's the point of `.small-block-grid-3 > li:nth-of-type(1n)`? This just selects every list item, so the `clear: none;` should be located in `.small-block-grid-3 > li`

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty LESS file to generate block grids (1 to `@grid-columns`) in Bootstrap 3. Still need to make responsive classes (like `block-grid-sm-3 block-grid-lg-6`).

```
// Bootstrap variables and mixisn
@import "bootstrap/less/variables.less";
@import "bootstrap/less/mixins.less";

.block-grid () {
  padding: 0;

  & > li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
  }
}

.make-block-grid (@columns, @spacing: @grid-gutter-width) when (@columns > 0) {
  .block-grid-@{columns} {
    &:extend(.clearfix all);
    .block-grid();

    margin: 0 (-@spacing / 2);

    > li {
      width: 100% / @columns;
      padding: 0 (@spacing / 2) @spacing;

      &:nth-of-type(1n) { clear: none; }
      &:nth-of-type(@{columns}n+1) { clear: both; }
    }
  }

  .make-block-grid(@columns - 1)
}

.make-block-grid(@grid-columns);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a responsive version gremo's answer:

```
.make-block-grid(@class, @columns: @grid-columns, @spacing: @grid-gutter-width) when (@columns > 0) {
  .block-grid-@{class}-@{columns} {
    .clearfix;

    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 (-@spacing / 2);

    & > li {
      display: block;

      float: left;

      width: 100% / @columns;
      padding: 0 (@spacing / 2) @spacing;

      list-style: none;

      &:nth-of-type(1n) {
        clear: none;
      }
      &:nth-of-type(@{columns}n+1) {
        clear: both;
      }
    }
  }

  .make-block-grid(@class, @columns - 1);
}

.make-block-grid(xs);

@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
  .make-block-grid(sm);
}

@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
  .make-block-grid(md);
}

@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
  .make-block-grid(lg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This css works for me:

```css
class*="block-grid-"] {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 -0.625rem;
  *zoom: 1; }
  [class*="block-grid-"]:before, [class*="block-grid-"]:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table; }
  [class*="block-grid-"]:after {
    clear: both; }
  [class*="block-grid-"] > li {
    display: inline;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }

@media only screen {
  .small-block-grid-1 > li {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .small-block-grid-1 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .small-block-grid-1 > li:nth-of-type(1n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .small-block-grid-2 > li {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .small-block-grid-2 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .small-block-grid-2 > li:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .small-block-grid-3 > li {
    width: 33.33333%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .small-block-grid-3 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .small-block-grid-3 > li:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .small-block-grid-4 > li {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .small-block-grid-4 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .small-block-grid-4 > li:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .small-block-grid-5 > li {
    width: 20%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .small-block-grid-5 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .small-block-grid-5 > li:nth-of-type(5n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .small-block-grid-6 > li {
    width: 16.66667%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .small-block-grid-6 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .small-block-grid-6 > li:nth-of-type(6n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .small-block-grid-7 > li {
    width: 14.28571%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .small-block-grid-7 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .small-block-grid-7 > li:nth-of-type(7n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .small-block-grid-8 > li {
    width: 12.5%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .small-block-grid-8 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .small-block-grid-8 > li:nth-of-type(8n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .small-block-grid-9 > li {
    width: 11.11111%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .small-block-grid-9 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .small-block-grid-9 > li:nth-of-type(9n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .small-block-grid-10 > li {
    width: 10%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .small-block-grid-10 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .small-block-grid-10 > li:nth-of-type(10n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .small-block-grid-11 > li {
    width: 9.09091%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .small-block-grid-11 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .small-block-grid-11 > li:nth-of-type(11n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .small-block-grid-12 > li {
    width: 8.33333%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .small-block-grid-12 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .small-block-grid-12 > li:nth-of-type(12n+1) {
      clear: both; } }
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) {
  .medium-block-grid-1 > li {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .medium-block-grid-1 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .medium-block-grid-1 > li:nth-of-type(1n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .medium-block-grid-2 > li {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .medium-block-grid-2 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .medium-block-grid-2 > li:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .medium-block-grid-3 > li {
    width: 33.33333%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .medium-block-grid-3 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .medium-block-grid-3 > li:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .medium-block-grid-4 > li {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .medium-block-grid-4 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .medium-block-grid-4 > li:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .medium-block-grid-5 > li {
    width: 20%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .medium-block-grid-5 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .medium-block-grid-5 > li:nth-of-type(5n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .medium-block-grid-6 > li {
    width: 16.66667%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .medium-block-grid-6 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .medium-block-grid-6 > li:nth-of-type(6n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .medium-block-grid-7 > li {
    width: 14.28571%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .medium-block-grid-7 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .medium-block-grid-7 > li:nth-of-type(7n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .medium-block-grid-8 > li {
    width: 12.5%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .medium-block-grid-8 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .medium-block-grid-8 > li:nth-of-type(8n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .medium-block-grid-9 > li {
    width: 11.11111%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .medium-block-grid-9 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .medium-block-grid-9 > li:nth-of-type(9n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .medium-block-grid-10 > li {
    width: 10%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .medium-block-grid-10 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .medium-block-grid-10 > li:nth-of-type(10n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .medium-block-grid-11 > li {
    width: 9.09091%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .medium-block-grid-11 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .medium-block-grid-11 > li:nth-of-type(11n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .medium-block-grid-12 > li {
    width: 8.33333%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .medium-block-grid-12 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .medium-block-grid-12 > li:nth-of-type(12n+1) {
      clear: both; } }
@media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em) {
  .large-block-grid-1 > li {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .large-block-grid-1 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .large-block-grid-1 > li:nth-of-type(1n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .large-block-grid-2 > li {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .large-block-grid-2 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .large-block-grid-2 > li:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .large-block-grid-3 > li {
    width: 33.33333%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .large-block-grid-3 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .large-block-grid-3 > li:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .large-block-grid-4 > li {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .large-block-grid-4 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .large-block-grid-4 > li:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .large-block-grid-5 > li {
    width: 20%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .large-block-grid-5 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .large-block-grid-5 > li:nth-of-type(5n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .large-block-grid-6 > li {
    width: 16.66667%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .large-block-grid-6 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .large-block-grid-6 > li:nth-of-type(6n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .large-block-grid-7 > li {
    width: 14.28571%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .large-block-grid-7 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .large-block-grid-7 > li:nth-of-type(7n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .large-block-grid-8 > li {
    width: 12.5%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .large-block-grid-8 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .large-block-grid-8 > li:nth-of-type(8n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .large-block-grid-9 > li {
    width: 11.11111%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .large-block-grid-9 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .large-block-grid-9 > li:nth-of-type(9n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .large-block-grid-10 > li {
    width: 10%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .large-block-grid-10 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .large-block-grid-10 > li:nth-of-type(10n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .large-block-grid-11 > li {
    width: 9.09091%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .large-block-grid-11 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .large-block-grid-11 > li:nth-of-type(11n+1) {
      clear: both; }

  .large-block-grid-12 > li {
    width: 8.33333%;
    padding: 0 0.625rem 1.25rem; }
    .large-block-grid-12 > li:nth-of-type(n) {
      clear: none; }
    .large-block-grid-12 > li:nth-of-type(12n+1) {
      clear: both; } }
```

```html
<ul class="small-block-grid-2 large-block-grid-4">
  <li><img src="../assets/img/examples/comet-th.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="../assets/img/examples/launch-th.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="../assets/img/examples/space-th.jpg"></li>
  <li><img src="../assets/img/examples/spacewalk-th.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```