# Converting Foundation's block grid to Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was looking at a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23204785/creating-a-foundation-style-block-grid-in-bootstrap-3).

But couldn't quite figure out how it was being used. I want to replicate the Foundation grid but for Bootstrap and having a hard time doing it seamlessly.

Here is what I'm attempting:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <ul class="block-grid-3">
            <li class="block-grid-3"><span>Testing one two three</span>
            </li>
            <li class="small-block-grid-3"><span>Testing one two three</span>
            </li>
            <li class="small-block-grid-3"><span>Testing one two three</span>
            </li>
            <li class="small-block-grid-3"><span>Testing one two three</span>
            </li>
            <li class="small-block-grid-3"><span>Testing one two three</span>
            </li>
            <li class="small-block-grid-3"><span>Testing one two three</span>
            </li>
            <li class="small-block-grid-3"><span>Testing one two three</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/70h9vf5c/

Ideally I'd be able to add: `small-block-grid-2 medium-block-grid-3 large-block-grid-4` to the `ul` and have it work for each screen size.

Comment: Can You give me the image like what you want? which layout you want?

Comment: @BindiyaPatoliya like the "Advanced" option here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html

Answer (score 0):

With just vanilla Bootstrap, I think you'd need to do something like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">Testing one two three</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">Testing one two three</div>
    ...
</div>
```

You could of course use Sass/Less to make it cleaner by aliasing e.g. `.my-grid-block` to `.col-sm-6.col-md-4.col-lg-3`.